# Melhor definição do EntityManager

Tags: java, jpa, cdi

Estou estudando sobre JPA juntamente com a Injeção de Dependências e li alguns pontos sobre o `EntityManager`:

Se usarmos o seguinte método:

```
public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("exemplo");
EntityManager entityManager = factory.createEntityManager();
factory.close();
return entityManager;
}
```

Estamos informando a unidade de persistência que está definida no arquivo `persistence.xml` e criando nosso `EntityManager`.

Eu li também que podemos usar assim:

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "exemplo")
  private EntityManager entityManager;
```

Ambos acima tem o mesmo efeito ?

Em relação a Injeção de dependência com `CDI` eu li que ao usar o `@Inject` em um objeto `EntityManager` dentro de um DAO por exemplo, o objeto `entityManager` vai possuir todas as suas dependências preenchidas. Mas se quisermos dizer ao `CDI` como o `EntityManager` deve ser instanciado, podemos criar um método em uma classe X com a anotação `@Produces`. Outra pergunta: O `@Produces` juntamente com o `@PersistenceContext` poderiam ser usados no método `getEntityManager()`? Para se carregar a unidade persistência definida no arquivo `persistence.xml` ou para criar nosso `EntityManager` precisa ser o método `main` ? Ou estes recursos já são lidos ao se iniciar um servidor de aplicação, no meu caso o `wildfly` ?

Comment: `@PersistenceContext` é utilizado quando se tem mais de uma unidade de persistência. Geralmente quando sua aplicação trabalha com vários bancos. Quando é necessário dizer em qual deles se deseja persistir, editar ou ler dados. Agora quanto a injeção de dependências, gerenciamento de escopos e transações, etc.. Sugiro dar uma lida sobre o Spring Framework. Ele facilita bastante essas tarefas, tem uma excelente documentação e uma comunidade muito ativa.

Answer (score 0):

Basicamente e a mesma coisa, a diferença crucial neste ponto é que em um, a JVM faz as magicas dela pra criar seu EntityManager e no outro você tem uma classe JPAUtil que trás para você esse Entity.

A melhor abordagem é a injeção pois assim você não tem que instanciar nada e nem se preocupar em como esse objeto vem e tudo mais, o java e o hibernate cuida de tudo e trás pra você, só precisa de um annotation em cima do seu atributo de classe geralmente e pronto, MAGIC.Acho bem interessante usar injeção de dependências porque quando você injeta ela, pelo menos CDI cuida de fechar as conexões, oque já ajuda bastante, geralmente da trabalho fechar as conexões da forma correta sem deixar ninguém sem ela...

O @PersistenceContext deve ser usado dentro de uma classe @Repository, como boa pratica, mais caso queira usar ele fora disso, até aonde eu sei, nada impede, faça testes, escreva pequenos códigos, veja os erros acontecer e compartilha com a gente os resultados das suas perguntas ai.